# Invoke amazon lambda from amazon connect - wrong input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to make a contact flow in amazon connect, in basic terms it should;

"Do you need support" -> Person: "Yes" -> "What is your name?" Person: "John doe", it should save "john doe" and send it to a lamba. this is how the contact flow looks like;

[image: Contactflow]

this is the code of my lambda;

[image: lambda]

error in CloudWatch, 
Lambda;
[image: lambdaerror]

connect;
[image: connect message]

I have tried a couple of different settings and variables in order to send the right value with it, and this is what is set as of right now;

[image: settings]

Comment: Does anyone know why the input looks this weird?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong attribute type when sending the firstname to the lambda. From the type drop down you should select either: User Defined and then use firstname as the key and the value or just select Lex Slots and reference the same value you do in your Set Contact Attributes block.

Also not familiar with Java Lambdas, but I do know connect sends your lambda a JSON object and it looks like you have input set as a string. May be worth looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, take into account different things:
1- You have to authorize amazon connect to trigger the lambda function.
2- You could send the data to lambda in different ways, for example if you have data in the same ContactFlow but it comes for previous part of the flow or store and send directly to lambda, see the image: 
[image]

This is how we receive tc_date

[image]

And this is how we receive tc_numero but we send to a lambda that encrypts and tc_numero lives in the flow and we called how I show you in first image

[image]